# GridView item not get selected for dragging in WindowsPhone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am facing the problem with dragging(DragItemsStarting) the item from GridView ,item pressed does not gets selected for dragging and could not drag the item in WindowsPhone 8.1.

Please find the tried code to dag the Grid view item.

```
  <GridView AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  SelectionMode="Single"
         DragItemsStarting="gridview_DragItemsStarting" Drop="schedule_Drop" Grid.Row="2"  x:Name="gridview"  BorderThickness="1"  BorderBrush="LightGray">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <GridViewItem.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border  Margin="10,20,0,0"  Height="70" Width="100"  BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock  Margin="1"   Text="Hi" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="#FF25A0DA" FontSize="10"/>
                                    <TextBlock  Margin="1"   Text="Forum" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Gray" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="10"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </GridViewItem.Template>
                </GridViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Pease share Suggestion to resolve this.

Regards,
Jeyasri M

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [ReorderMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.reordermode) property to enable reordering of gridviewitems. And also in the itemtemplate of the gridview you are creating a gridviewitem inside the gridviewitemtemplate.

Have you data template as below:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border  Margin="10,20,0,0"  Height="70" Width="100"  BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                         <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                          <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <TextBlock  Margin="1"   Text="Hi" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="#FF25A0DA" FontSize="10"/>
                     <TextBlock  Margin="1"   Text="Forum" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Gray" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="10"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```